# Object moves when saved

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I have a 3D beaver that I have made in Blender, before I saved it, his head was firmly on his body but as soon as I save it and reopen, the head (which is one object of joined components) appears like this:
[image]
**Of additional note:** the ears have some bendy modifications (I am a newbie in Blender so followed a stuffed bear tutorial and changed it a bit).
I know the answer is probably simple, have I missed a step in my building of the model?
There is nothing else special about it, it's simply spheres and cylinders with the basic diffuse material. Apologies for my inability but I have yet to find something Googling.

Comment: the animation is the reason for that since you have some key-frame  if you move the head than save it and reopen it will go back to where the animation move it

Comment: Thank you! You can tell I am new at this but I want to learn and you have helped! Should I just delete the keyfrmaes?

Comment: I'm glad to help the devil :) ,if you don't need those keyframes you can delete theme "or some of them "

Comment: @Chebhou please write your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The head has an animation, so when you move it and save then reopen its position will be overridden by the animation you created